# In which symfony file do i need to create entity functions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am confused that in which file i need to create symfony functions.

E,g

I have class User.php and .

Now i have many functions

like

`addUser()` , `editUser()`, `sleectUserBySubject()` , `findUserBydate()`

Now i don't know where should i declare these

```
Entity\User.php
UserController.php
UserRepository.php
Model\User.php
```

EDIT: Now for what purpose i can use `UserManager.php`. Still confused which function will come there

Please guide which is the best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the methods are simply used to query the DB for a group of `User` entities, use a `UserRepository` class (`selectUserBySubject()` and `findUserByDate()` are good candidates for repository methods *if* they don't rely on any other classes). If the methods are more complex, and/or deal with business logic, use a [service class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service).

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479286/155175) regarding the best place for business logic.

Comment: I agree with you. But still i have not found any example where i can see service class defined and being used. IN symfony sites its only code snippet but i want to know in folder to define , i mean  `services\userService.php` or  and how to inject the dependencies

Comment: Services are just classes, and can be stored wherever you like. Be sure to read the Symfony2 docs on the service container (linked in my answer) - it goes over all the details you'll need to know.

Comment: @Zombie15 You might also want to check out my brief description of the service layer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416249/155175

Answer (score 0):

In `UserRepository.php`, you could consider `Repository` class as the data manage class.

Comment: I used sensio CRUD Generator and it put all its functions in controller only. so do i need to move functions in repository or i can leave edit , delete , list in controller , because i also need to define routes as well using annottion

Comment: @user54418 It is better to have query logic in Repository class.

Comment: also which functions will come in `UserManager.php`